# Dados do form não aparecem

Tags: php, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo uma app, em Ionic, um cadastro de endereços.

Após o `form` preenchido, adicionei um *console.log(endereco)* no `controler` para ver os dados, clico no botão salvar e os dados não aparecem e ainda diz que *console.log(endereco)* é `undefined`.

Seguem os códigos

**Html:**

```
<ion-view title="Endereco" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header">
    <form name="enderecoForm" class="list">
        <ion-list>
            <div ng-controller="enderecoCtrl">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-blur="pegaCep()" placeholder="CEP">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.uf" placeholder="Estado">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cidade" placeholder="Cidade">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.bairro" placeholder="Bairro">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.logradouro" placeholder="Logradouro">
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="adicionarEndereco(endereco)">Salvar</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('enderecoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.pegaCep = function () { 
$http.get("php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (endereco){
        $scope.endereco = endereco;
    });
 }

$scope.adicionarEndereco = function (endereco){
    console.log(endereco);

}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o `ng-controller="enderecoCtrl"` deve cobrir todo formulário ate o button do submit.

Veja que button submit esta fora do escopo do controlador, não é conhecido.

Veja Minha solução. Coloca ng-controller="enderecoCtrl" em `ion-content`

```
<ion-view title="Endereco" hide-back-button="true">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header" ng-controller="enderecoCtrl">
    <form name="enderecoForm" class="list">
        <ion-list>
            <div>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-blur="pegaCep()" placeholder="CEP">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.uf" placeholder="Estado">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cidade" placeholder="Cidade">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.bairro" placeholder="Bairro">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.logradouro" placeholder="Logradouro">
                </label>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
        <button class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="adicionarEndereco(endereco)">Salvar</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```